# Swipe Gesture Recognizer (Swift 2.0 xCode 7.2)

Tags: ios, xcode

So I am putting together my first iOS app after moving away from a web based "app" compiler for PhoneGap. It's a steep learning curve! :)

I have created multiple views and setup my basic navigation between them all.

I want to incorporate Swipe Navigation to allow users to navigate back to the previous view.

I have managed to get this working (of sorts) but I have a couple of issues:

If I select to "Present Modally" I get the animation I want (Cross Dissolve Transition) but when returning to the previous view, the links/button navigations don't work anymore.

If I select "reveal view controller push controller" I lose the animation I want (cross dissolve) but when swiping back, the links/button navigations do continue to work.

Any help is very much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you embedded your view controller in a Navigation Controller?

Comment: Hi, yes they are. Here's an image of the current Storyboard with some notes which may help: http://imageshack.com/a/img633/3823/JcXtNg.png

As mentioned, the navigation does work with the 2nd option, just not the first option with the transition selected.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use custom segues and/or animations? If yes please show some code. You can also edit your question and e.g. put the image in there.

Comment: Thank Qbyte,

So I habe a segue from the red View back to the Nav Controller of the parent View. 
This gives me a nice animation by default (page flip) but when it takes me back to the parent view which contains my menu button and another button with a graphic, they no longer work. 

I can provide some code, just not sure what code you need :)

http://imageshack.com/a/img905/926/dKr8ji.png